# c++ Program won't run properly on Mac but will on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11

```
/*********************************************************************************************
* Function: Appends the Node newelement to the end of the List
*********************************************************************************************/
void append(const T &newelement)
{
    Node *N = new Node(newelement);

    if(first == (Node*)0)
    {
        first = N;
        last = N;
        _length = 1;

    }
    else
    {
        last->insertNodeAfter(N);
        last = N;
        _length++;
    }
};

/*********************************************************************************************
* Function: Appends the Node newelement to the end of the List
*********************************************************************************************/
void prepend(const T &newelement)
{
    Node *N = new Node(newelement);

    if(first == (Node*)1)
    {
        first = N;
        last = N;
        _length = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        first->insertNodeBefore(N);
        first = N;
        _length++;
    }
};
```

AS PEOPLE have told me off, I've narrowed it down to this code sort of... it breaks when its trying to ADD a node to the List. Giving me access errors and such. (BUT ONLY SOMETIMES)

Comment: [TL;DR¡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR) Please try to narrow down the code to only the problematic parts, for example by debugging.  Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Im not sure where the bug is, the code runs perfectly fine on windows but not on mac. Ive tried to narrow it down to something but I haven't been able to because it breaks at different stages each time I run it on the Mac.

Comment: Memory errors such as it seems you are being warned about exhibit ***undefined behavior***, as indeed sounds reasonable for your observations.  If your program has undefined behavior then there is no reasoning, from the C++ perspective, about why it behaves as it does.  Get your memory management straight first.

Comment: @MichaelMariani That's usually a symptom of you had been hitten by undefined behavior invoked.

Comment: Use memory debugging tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) (or similar) to help you find the problem. Or of course just step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, for example `first == (Node*)1` (in `prepend`) is illegal/undefined and will give random behavior. Depending on memory layout of the chip and the OS, this will survive, work sometimes, work always, fail randomly, or fail always. It is not surprising at all that a Mac and a x86 chip behave differently.

There are multiple other assumption in the code, like an `int` is large enough for things; etc.

All these rules that people tend to gloss over have a reason, and many of these errors you get away with on one architecture,but not on another one.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of first == (Node*)1 This isn't whats breaking the it sometimes. Sometimes its append.

Comment: I suspect `(Node*)1` is a typo for `(Node*)0`. The right thing to use is `nullptr`, it doesn't need to be cast.

Comment: @MichaelMariani When you have undefined behavior, it doesn't necessarily die in the same code that's causing the problem. Undefined behavior often corrupts memory in a way that doesn't get noticed until much later.

Answer (score 1):

Before you erroneously removed the relevant parts of your code from the question, the bug was fairly obvious.

DoubleLinkedNode's constructor fails to initialize the `nextNode` and `previousNode` class members to NULL. This results in undefined behavior.

Just because a C++ program crashes on a particular line, that doesn't mean that's where the bug is.

You are crashing when you're adding a new node to the list.

But the bug is that `insertNodeAfter()` is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. And the bug is because the constructor is failing to initialize them to NULL.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you, I didn't write the code it was given to us to figure out bugs. I found most of them and got the code working at uni but when i got home it would just break on my mac.